# Using XmlComment for swagger api helper page

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, swagger

I got error when try to config swagger for my new start ASP.NET Core api project. It work perfectly on local host : the comment work good with xml comment. But when I publish it to azure host, it doesn't work.

[image: Azure error message]

Then I tried to find out the way is comment the config code which add xml comment to swagger :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMvcCore().AddApiExplorer();
    services.AddLogging();
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = " API Helper Page",
            Description = "A simple start ASP.NET Core Web API/ MBAAS",
            TermsOfService = "None",
            Contact = new Contact { Name = "Nguyễn Bá Nguyên", Email = "", Url = "https://github.com/hello/" },
            License = new License { Name = "Under Construction...", Url = " " }
        });
        // Set the comments path for the swagger json and ui.
        // only working on local, need to be fixed
        var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, ".xml");
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });

}
```

to get publish to azure without bug I commented the last

```
 //var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
                //var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, ".xml");
                //c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath

);
```

and azure host worked but swagger can't use xml comment :(

[image: Documentation without comments]

So is there any way to config swagger to use xml comment for azure host?

Comment: Try explicitly include the generated xml file in your project, then it should be included in the publish to azure step, and be available without you having to upload manually via kudu/FTP.

Comment: @rory_za do you know howPlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath find the xml comment file ( which auto generate when we config : Solution explorer ->properties->build->output-> click to check box of XML documentation file and chose Output path). So  where should i include the generated xml file from auto generate?

Comment: Set it to build the file then build the project at least once, then just add the generated file as an "existing item" to your project.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue using swagger xml comments with .NET core on Azure API App. After I set the `stdoutLogEnabled` flag to `true` within the web.config I figured out that the **XML file is missing**. After I uploaded the xml file manually to the API it worked.

To upload the XML file you can use the Kudu service (either type `<yourapi>.scm.azurewebsites.net` or within the app in the Azure portal -> Development Tools -> Advanced Tools). Then click on Debug console, navigate to your site and upload the xml file:

[image]

Comment: actually i don't know how PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath find the xml comment file ( which auto generate when we config : Solution explorer ->properties->build->output-> click to check box of XML documentation file and chose Output path)

Comment: @MartinBrandl: Why uploading manually when you can set the files to be published via project.json / csproj? XD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#files

Comment: @Tseng You are right, thats probably the way to go. Anyhow, the answer to his question is that the XML file is missing, thus the API doesn't start.

Comment: I'd be more interested why his code works locally in the first place, because he is combing the base path with ".xml" without a filename, which should result in a  path like `X:\MyProj\Project.WebApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\.xml` instead of `X:\MyProj\Project.WebApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Project.WebApi.xml`

Comment: because my xml file is ".xml" :))

Comment: you are right, didn't noticed that. But looks like the file is called .xml without extension :D.

Comment: @Tseng could you help me find out how to set files to be  published via csproj, is it the file :VNPTThanhHoa_WebAPI.csproj (VNPTThanhHoa_WebAPI is project name)